# Programming Java - variables?

Tags: java

```
int size; 

//constructor 
useBook(){}; 

useBook (int siz) { 
book=new Book[siz]; 
size=siz;
```

Can anyone please explain the use of each of these variables and what they are being used for in this given example?
The siz is the variable being used to give the size to the array but what is the variable int size being used for?

Answer (score 1):

The only 2 variables being used here are size and siz.  If a useBook is created with the `useBook (int siz)` constructor, the int specified is assigned to size and that's it!  Not much can be said about the line `book=new Book[siz];` since the constructor info provided relates to useBook rather than Book. The constructor has to have the same name as the class.

Comment: `size` isn't a variable, it's a field.

Comment: Non-static fields are also known as instance variables because their values are unique to each instance of a class.